# How do I force derived classes to include a static property?

Tags: php

How can I enforce the rule that derived classes should contain some static property or value?

in this example I'm looking to ensure that every class which extends Parent should contain a static variable $foo

```
abstract class Parent{
    // Trying to enforce that all derived classes must contain a static $foo;
    static protected $foo;

    public function getFoo(){
        return get_class($this)::$foo;
    }

}

class Child extends Parent{
     static protected $foo = 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't. Why not make it an abstract method that would allow children to implement it the way *they* want, instead of limiting it to a static value?

Comment: Thanks. It just seemed dryer to have just one definition of the getFoo() method contained within the abstract class than to have to define it anew inside each child class.

Comment: If you're going to force your children to implement *something*, then it hardly matters whether you force them to implement a static property or a method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot `abstract` a class property however in this case it is probably better to do the following:

```
abstract class Parent{      
    abstract public function getFoo();
}

class Child extends Parent{
    private $foo = 0;

    public function getFoo(){
        return $this->foo;
    }
}
```

As an additional note for you to know in the future where you did `get_class($this)::$foo` that is not necessary and you can just do `static::$foo` which works the same.